# Purpose of this SQL

Tags: sql, constraints

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
```

I have searched about check constraint. Generally, it limits the range of data.
But, I'm not clear about check constraint without parameter. What is the purpose of this SQL?

Comment: What database management system are you using? What is the context of this statement? This forum can tell you what it does, but we can't speak to it's purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ALTER TABLE CHECK CONSTRAINT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/24297/140985) on Database Administrators.